# Modal Window as an Excel Sheet

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel, vsto

How can i have a modal window which behaves as an excel sheet?
Also the modal window should only have the excel cells visible and not the Ribbon tabs
(Home, Insert, Page Layout, etc).

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you trying to provide a "view" of a worksheet from within your application, or are you trying to do something from within Excel?

Comment: just like a google sheets now have a table chart. which floats on top of the spreadsheet. it will be very interesting to have a "non modal" sheet that can show data of main window.. and say pressing a button will show underlying data on the floating window say with O365 filter function.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get a control like grape city's Spread.Net.

http://www.gcpowertools.com/Products/SpreadNET